# Detecting missing timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have following dataframe having a timestamp and value. Timestamp increases by 5 seconds and notice that there are missing records between 23:02:02 & 23:06:32.

Is there a simple way to detect if there are missing records between timestamps?

```
timestamp   value
23:01:27    2915
23:01:32    2916
23:01:37    2919
23:01:42    2924
23:01:47    2926
23:01:52    2928
23:01:57    2933
23:02:02    2937 # <- missing timestamp
23:06:32    3102 # <- between these lines
23:06:37    3109
23:06:42    3114
23:06:47    3122
23:06:52    3126
23:06:57    3129
```

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to indicate *where* you are missing timestamps, you can convert to datetime and use `diff` to see the time difference between rows, then  use `>'00:00:05'` to see if the gap is greater than 5 seconds:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).diff() > '00:00:05'
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

This indicates you are missing records above index `8`

If your goal is simply to see *whether* you are missing timestamps, use `any`:

```
>>> (pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).diff() > '00:00:05').any()
True
```

Indicating that you are indeed missing timestamps somewhere

**[EDIT]** as per @JoranBeasley's suggestion, you can also use the mode of your time differences to infer the desired frequency:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).diff()

>>> (d > d.mode()[0])
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

Because `d.mode()[0]` will return the most common frequency observed:

```
>>> d.mode()[0]
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:05')
```

Comment: If the OP just wants to know if there are *any* missing records in the data, couldn't they just compare the number of expected records in the set for that time-frame with the actual number of records? Even if they don't know the time-frame offhand, couldn't we take a time difference between the first and last record to find that information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to calculate the difference between adjacent timestamps are greater than a certain threshold (e.g. 7 seconds).